# Pygame Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, pygame, multiplayer

I have a multiplayer game that runs on pygame. I am running the game/client/server in separate threads and have a simple echo server. Each time a player broadcasts a message, every other player will get it. The problem I am experiencing is pygame has a while(true) loop that redraws the screen every 10 milliseconds. This loop causes the game world to not get updated since it cannot do anything outside the loop. I tried using a queue so that in the while loop, it can dequeue and process the commands however that doesnt seem to work (q.put() places nothing in the queue).

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Here is a snippet of the architecture:

```
class Client(Thread, Observer):
    #waits for notifications from ClientSocket
    #starts the game loop
    #enqueue commands in the Game

class ClientSocket(Thread, Observable):
    #observes the socket and notifies the Client

class Server(Thread):
    #simply broadcasts commands to ClientSocket(s)

class Game(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = queue.Queue()

    while True:
        #delay 10 ms
        #redraw
        #see if u need to process queue
```

Comment: you do realize that `CPython` isn't truly concurrent and only runs one thread at time because of the `GIL` right?

Comment: hmm so any ideas on what I can try? My chat works perfectly however the pygame seems to be breaking everything.

Comment: Parhaps it's better if you post more code. Are you placing your main loop inside de run() mehtod in Game class?  Are you using game.start() in Client class?

Comment: You are right, I am doing game.start() in the Client. I partially got it working after fixing all my exception errors so I guess this is resolved for now.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you to read carefully Queue docs http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html and threading docs http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html. Your decision to use `while True:` does not look very well. Please read about locks/semaphores/mutex/events and check these simple examples http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm and I am sure that you will be able to create better multithreading architecture.

Comment: Its not my decision...pygame needs the while True to redraw items on the screen. My code works fine, its just when coupled with pygame, its not working properly. I may need to use an event driven design....